# Create an Icon from an Image downloaded from the Internet

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, icons, webclient

I would like to use an Image taken from an Internet address and use it the Icon of one or more Forms in my application.
I don't want to save it on disk. I tried it and had some errors when drawing the bitmap.

So far I have something like this:

```
internal static Icon DownloadImage(string fromUrl)
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(fromUrl))
        {
            return new Icon(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

The last line was originally optimized for images, like this:

```
return Image.FromStream(stream);
```

That's where it got tricky and I don't know how to get further.
It's not working in the current state, I want to call it like this:

```
this.Icon = DownloadImage(url);
```

Can anyone help me with this?
I am trying to use a `.svg` image, but technically it could be any file format.

Comment: The recommended way is to create a real ie multi resolution icon with an icon editor and load it into your assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Image.FromStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream) and cast to Bitmap, so you have the [GetHicon()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.gethicon) method available.
If the Image doesn't need any special treatment, then just return [Icon.FromHandle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle), passing the value returned by `GetHicon()` to the method.

The bool option in `FromStream(stream, true)` instructs to preserve ICM information, if present. If it's present, discarding it may compromise the Color definition of the image.

If the image is already transparent, the Icon will preserve the transparency setting.

Remember to call the `Dispose()` method (to destroy the handle) of your new Icon when the Form closes or before you replace it with another.

Note: in the question, the SVG format is mentioned. GDI+ doesn't support this format, as WebP and other more recent formats. See: [Using Image Encoders and Decoders in Managed GDI+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-image-encoders-and-decoders-in-managed-gdi)

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;

internal static Icon GetIconFromWebImage(string fromUrl)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(new Uri(fromUrl)))
    using (var img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream, true)) {
        return Icon.FromHandle(img.GetHicon());
    }
}
```

You can the set:

```
[Some Form].Icon = DownloadImage([some address]);
```

Comment: Sorry. As I said, the error message says "invalid parameter".
I am trying to download: https://web.whatsapp.com/img/favicon_c5088e888c97ad440a61d247596f88e5.png

Comment: No, I tried it with your line of code, not working either. I tried to Change the Project Architecture to x86 and this time my firewall asked if I want to allow access to the internet. I clicked yes, but the error came again.
The error happens at system. drawing (see below).
This project is completely new, I just open a new form with a button and want to change the icon in the constructor.

System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message= Invalid parameter.
  Source = System.Drawing

Comment: I pasted the code like how you posted it here. I use it in another class and call the class from the constructor in the form.
In the form I use `this.Icon = [class].DownloadImage`

Comment: You didn't say in what System is this code run and what is the .Net version in use. -- I cannot reproduce the problem: [Form with Icon](https://imgur.com/a/pNKpcwt). -- You can also update your question, how / when you're calling this code.

Comment: I use Windows 10 Pro and -NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: All right. So TLS12 is active. Have you tried another address, to see if you have the same result? Is the Firewall or an anti-virus blocking connections, for some reason? You shouldn't get a permission request from a Firewall while running the app in Visual Studio. The exception from `Image.FormStream()` says that the address cannot be reached (no Stream), or the image is not compatible (that's not the case, from what I can see), or the server dropped the connection right away (again, no Stream).

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know why I haven't tried it before. With other Images it works fine, thank you so much :D

Comment: Well, find out why it doesn't work with that one. As you can see in the image I linked, I can reach it without problem. Maybe you'll face the same issue some other time with some other address and you don't know what happens.

Comment: I don't know why it happened, I recorded it if you want to see: https://streamable.com/udfk9b
I can also use a PNG or JPEG, there are many sources for the logos I want to use.

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the line that sets the WebView's address (BTW, I don't see where you're initializing the WebView object)?  -- It takes a long time to throw that exception, as if it had trouble connecting.

Answer (score 0):

it is safer to use `return Image.FromStream(stream);` so you can refer to any image..

then

```
Bitmap myBitmap = DownloadImage(url);
IntPtr Hicon = myBitmap.GetHicon();
Icon newIcon = Icon.FromHandle(Hicon);
this.Icon = newIcon;
DestroyIcon(newIcon.Handle);
```